# Is there a way to perform a cross join on two tables in Excel using VBA/Power Query?

Tags: excel, powerquery, cross-join

What I have currently are two worksheets: one that is a rolling list of company projects that will be added to every so often, and another that provides a list of tasks that are associated with every project (about 110 tasks). My ideal state is where our administrator adds a new project to the project sheet, I want to run a script or process that adds all new projects (denoted by [project id]) to a master sheet (where every time this runs, it will append the new data to the bottom of the records), and makes a row for every task, with the task in an adjacent column. [edit] - This process will need to be automated, either by way of scheduled refresh or a button/trigger initiated by the recording of the new project(s).

*Project Table*

| Project ID | Attribute |
| --- | --- |
| PID1 | XXXXX |
| PID2 | XXXXX |
| PID3 | XXXXX |

*Task Table*

| Checkpoint | Task |
| --- | --- |
| CP1 | Task 1 |
| CP2 | Task 2 |
| CP3 | Task 3 |

*New Table*

| Project ID | Checkpoint | Task |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PID1 | CP1 | Task 1 |
| PID1 | CP2 | Task 2 |
| PID1 | CP3 | Task 3 |
| PID2 | CP1 | Task 1 |
| PID2 | CP2 | Task 2 |
| PID2 | CP3 | Task 3 |

I wanted to run SQL to get this done, because that would be done easily, but I cannot figure out how to do that without using Power Automate. However, I can't use PA because these files are on SharePoint and that requires a different license than what I have.

I tried using Power Query, but since I do not have any common columns, I can't get the correct columns to populate to a flat table. I also tried Power Automate but ran into the licensing issue. I have entertained the idea of using Access but have not done anything with that yet.

Comment: Will there be any data entry in the resulting table?

Comment: @SamNseir - eventually yes, there will dates added. But I can make that another sheet if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Load both tables as queries. Then in one add a custom column and for the formula simply refer to the other query (e.g. if you are in Projects, use =Tasks as the formula). That will create a table for each row. Then simply expand the table using the double-headed arrow at the top of the column.

Comment: The arrow expansion buttons helps, but I need this to be automated (probably should have mentioned that). I need there to be either a trigger button/action or a scheduled refresh that does this automatically.

Comment: If you file close and load it , then right click (or use VBA or auto refresh upon open) to refresh the output, then its automated

Comment: @horseyride - you're correct, that does help my automation issue. However this method does not append any data, only overwrites everything. I may be able to make that work, but I'd rather have a wholistic solution and use this as a backup.

Comment: You are correct.  PowerQuery does not do appending.  You have to fake it by storing old data

Answer (score 0):

This answer also uses Power Query and is very similar to the previous answer, but this one only appends new rows to the main table while retaining any additional columns with data entry.

Queries in Power Query:

| Query | Load To … |
| --- | --- |
| tblProject | Connection only |
| tblTask | Connection only |
| tblMain Existing | Connection only |
| tblMain | Table |

Queries `tblProject`, `tblTask`, `tblMain Existing` - are simple and pull in the respective table in the worksheets.

Query `tblMain` is the one that does all the work and it is also the one that loads in as Table. `tblMain Existing` loads in this same table from the worksheet. Steps of `tblMain`:

- Reference `tblProject`
- Left Anti (rows only in the first) merge with `tblMain Existing` on `ProjectID`. This will leave you with only the new projects added since last refresh.
- Remove column of the merge
- Add a new column `Tasks` referencing `tblTask` (same as previous answer)
- Expand Tasks
- Append `tblMain - Existing` with the previous step
  `= Table.Combine({#"tblMain Existing", #"Expanded Tasks"})`

I've created a sample spreadsheet: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AtpcKzRsDrY1o7Vk6bgpWE8AH7wTqw?e=umWQ8x

Comment: Did this answer your question?